# Do chars have intrinsic int values in Java?

Tags: java, char, int

Why does this code print 97? I have not previously assigned 97 to 'a' anywhere else in my code.

```
public static void permutations(int n) {
    System.out.print('a' + 0);
}
```

Comment: Character literals in Java are 16-bit integer constants representing Unicode UCS-16 encoding values (not quite the same as Unicode code points, which are 21 bits).

Comment: Read [the Java tutorial on Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html)

Comment: char is an unsigned short value as all data is ultimately a binary number. The encoding is standard utf-16. This letter is one of the ASCII standard characters. It's encoding predates java by a few decades.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is of type `char` and chars can be implicitly converted to `int`. `a` is represented by 97 as this is the codepoint of `small latin letter a`.

```
System.out.println('a'); // this will print out "a"

// If we cast it explicitly:
System.out.println((int)'a'); // this will print out "97"

// Here the cast is implicit:
System.out.println('a' + 0); // this will print out "97"
```

The first call calls `println(char)`, and the other calls are to `println(int)`.

**Related:** [In what encoding is a Java char stored in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019504/in-what-encoding-is-a-java-char-stored-in)

Comment: I'm extremely hesitant to say that it can be implicitly converted to `int`; in most implementations it *is* an `int` with a much more restricted bound.

Comment: In java terms, it is different datatype. While it is right to say that both are _integer_ data types (like `byte` or `long` are), they have different sizes and are distinct data types. While saying it is being `cast` would be right, sign-extending conversion also takes place.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. `char`(s) have intrinsic `int` value in Java. The [JLS-4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) says (in part),

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> ...
>
> For `char`, from `'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'` inclusive, that is, from `0` to `65535`

And of course, when you perform integer arithmetic (`'a' + 0`) the result is an `int`.

[JLS-4.2.2. Integer Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) says in part,

> The numerical operators, which result in a value of type `int` or `long`:
>
> ...
>
> The additive operators + and - ([§15.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18))

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println('a' + 0); // prints out '97'
```

'a' is implicitly converted to its unicode value (that's 97) and 0 is an integer.
So: int + int --> int

```
System.out.println('a' + "0"); // prints out 'a0'
```

So: char + string --> string

Answer (score 1):

Because `'a'` has been implicitly converted to its unicode value summing it with 0.